# Checking existence and syncing data with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I am developing sms based service platform. In India, we have two different types of routes to send sms - promo & trans. Sms sent via promo route has to be checked against nationally maintained database (DND), which currently holds 231450000 mobile numbers.

My question is

1. What is the efficient way to store this data (DND).
2. What is the efficient way to check, whether the number exists within these numbers or not.
3. Twice in a week, a delta dump of these numbers (DND) is provided by telecom authority. How to sync the dump with existing db.
4. Should I use mysql to store this data, which will consist of mobile numbers, or any other in-memory storage?

EDIT:

1. Each row of data consists of mobile number alongwith few preferences like area code, user preference etc
2. The data dump provided twice a week contains only additions / deletions and not the whole data.
3. Lookup frequency can be very large. Actually every SMS sent from the platform has to first make a lookup against the data (DND). So if the platform is handling 100 sms per second, it has to make 100 lookups per second against this data. The lookup simply checks existence of a particular mobile number against the data(DND) in database.
4. The new delta data dump (additions / deletions), has to be synced in few hours only, as the dump is provided by telecom authority in the day and the same has to go live by midnight 00:00 hours. So the total time to sync data will be around 3 hours.

**Sample DND dump**

[image: Sample of DND dump provided. Here <code>A</code> under <code>Opstype</code> means record has to be added, while as <code>D</code> means record has to be deleted.]

Sample of DND dump provided. Here `A` under `Opstype` means record has to be added, while as `D` means record has to be deleted.

Comment: Sounds like you should talk to a vendor who is familiar with this problem.  Your question is much to broad for this forum.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with vendor. They simply provide a dump in csv format of mobile numbers and that dump has to be synced with database. New data inserted and non-existent data removed.

Comment: You have shown us a very large project here, but not provided many details. You have a quarter-gigarow (23 crore) collection of data that's updated twice a week. You don't say what is in each row of the collection. Is it just the number? You don't say how many lookups per second are required, or what those lookups must retrieve.You don't say whether the twice-weekly updates entirely replace the existing collection or contain a sequence of adds and deletes.  You don't say how long you have to go live with each twice-weekly updates. Do you have ten hours? a day? three days?

Comment: @OllieJones - Question updated. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's right. This application is large and demanding, and it seems likely that mistakes or failures can get you into trouble with clients or with authorities.

Can MySQL handle the lookup load? On a load-balanced cluster of servers with failover, probably it can. But it is a big load.

On the other hand, if you load this dataset into an in-memory data structure like a C# dictionary or a Java hash map, it will probably fit tolerably well in a 16 GiB server running a 64-bit operating system. You could build a simple web service to answer your queries. You could load-balance a bunch of these servers, so if one crashes you can rely on the others while it reloads.

You could also use redis or memcached for this data. That kind of solution is likely to be more scalable and easier to operate than an equivalently sized MySQL solution.

If you're wise, you'll size this system to handle a steady query load at least 1.5 times the size of your imagined peak load. That will give you some margin for overload.

A big question: do you have to cut over to the updated data all at once precisely at midnight? Or can you start using some new data as soon as you have it?

Comment: Data can be consumed as soon as we have it, but the updation has to be done before midnight.